# iOS: Capture image from front facing camera

Tags: ios, camera

I am making an application where I would like to capture an image from the front facing camera, without presenting a capture screen of any kind. I want to take a picture completely in code without any user interaction. How would I do this for the front facing camera?

Comment: You mean silently capture the image without the user knowing anything about it?

Comment: Yes, I know it sounds bad but its totally harmless. The app will cause them to pull a funny face and I want to capture it so they can see how silly they look.

Comment: Your implementation of such a feature may be harmless, but I can think of lots of other instances where it would be anything but (which is probably why it's not possible).

Answer (score 40):

How to capture an image using the AVFoundation front-facing camera:

Development Caveats:

- Check your app and image orientation settings carefully
- AVFoundation and its associated frameworks are nasty behemoths and very difficult to understand/implement. I've made my code as lean as possible, but please check out this excellent tutorial for a better explanation (website not available any more, link via archive.org):
  [http://www.benjaminloulier.com/posts/ios4-and-direct-access-to-the-camera](https://web.archive.org/web/20151231002415/http://www.benjaminloulier.com/posts/ios4-and-direct-access-to-the-camera)

ViewController.h

```
// Frameworks
#import <CoreVideo/CoreVideo.h>
#import <CoreMedia/CoreMedia.h>
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface CameraViewController : UIViewController <AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate>

// Camera
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView* cameraImageView;
@property (strong, nonatomic) AVCaptureDevice* device;
@property (strong, nonatomic) AVCaptureSession* captureSession;
@property (strong, nonatomic) AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer* previewLayer;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIImage* cameraImage;

@end
```

ViewController.m

```
#import "CameraViewController.h"

@implementation CameraViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self setupCamera];
    [self setupTimer];
}

- (void)setupCamera
{    
    NSArray* devices = [AVCaptureDevice devicesWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
    for(AVCaptureDevice *device in devices)
    {
        if([device position] == AVCaptureDevicePositionFront)
            self.device = device;
    }

    AVCaptureDeviceInput* input = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:self.device error:nil];
    AVCaptureVideoDataOutput* output = [[AVCaptureVideoDataOutput alloc] init];
    output.alwaysDiscardsLateVideoFrames = YES;

    dispatch_queue_t queue;
    queue = dispatch_queue_create("cameraQueue", NULL);
    [output setSampleBufferDelegate:self queue:queue];

    NSString* key = (NSString *) kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey;
    NSNumber* value = [NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInt:kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA];
    NSDictionary* videoSettings = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:value forKey:key];
    [output setVideoSettings:videoSettings];

    self.captureSession = [[AVCaptureSession alloc] init];
    [self.captureSession addInput:input];
    [self.captureSession addOutput:output];
    [self.captureSession setSessionPreset:AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto];

    self.previewLayer = [AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer layerWithSession:self.captureSession];
    self.previewLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill;

    // CHECK FOR YOUR APP
    self.previewLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.height, self.view.frame.size.width);
    self.previewLayer.orientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientationLandscapeRight;
    // CHECK FOR YOUR APP

    [self.view.layer insertSublayer:self.previewLayer atIndex:0];   // Comment-out to hide preview layer

    [self.captureSession startRunning];
}

- (void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)captureOutput didOutputSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection
{
    CVImageBufferRef imageBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer);
    CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(imageBuffer,0);
    uint8_t *baseAddress = (uint8_t *)CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(imageBuffer);
    size_t bytesPerRow = CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRow(imageBuffer);
    size_t width = CVPixelBufferGetWidth(imageBuffer);
    size_t height = CVPixelBufferGetHeight(imageBuffer);

    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    CGContextRef newContext = CGBitmapContextCreate(baseAddress, width, height, 8, bytesPerRow, colorSpace, kCGBitmapByteOrder32Little | kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst);
    CGImageRef newImage = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(newContext);

    CGContextRelease(newContext);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);

    self.cameraImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:newImage scale:1.0f orientation:UIImageOrientationDownMirrored];

    CGImageRelease(newImage);

    CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(imageBuffer,0);
}

- (void)setupTimer
{
    NSTimer* cameraTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2.0f target:self selector:@selector(snapshot) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}

- (void)snapshot
{
    NSLog(@"SNAPSHOT");
    self.cameraImageView.image = self.cameraImage;  // Comment-out to hide snapshot
}

@end
```

Connect this up to a UIViewController with a UIImageView for the snapshot and it'll work! Snapshots are taken programmatically at 2.0 second intervals without any user input. Comment out the selected lines to remove the preview layer and snapshot feedback.

Any more questions/comments, please let me know!

Comment: Very nice! I'd recommend this answer be accepted over mine (assuming it works).

Comment: Is this going to be Apple App Store friendly?

Comment: I'm not sure, this is the first time I've given thought to an app like this. I guess you'd need to dig into the fine print and really make the user/Apple know that it's not being used for any sinister purposes (as mentioned in other posts here). Your app does sound fun and harmless, so maybe it will be ok!

Comment: Yea I agree but the app review process is very strict and (at times) senseless. Many of the policies are arbitrary and don't make accommodations for "harmless" applications. Thanks for the code!

Comment: any quality considerations to know when using AVCaptureVideoDataOutput?

Comment: Ricardo, thanks a million for this great answer.  Setting aside the "no preview" aspect, it's just a great example of CoreMedia, AVFoundation etc.  Thanks again!

Comment: Does anyone know how to enable sound in this piece of code? I could bet Apple rejects this process..

Comment: kCGBitmapByteOrder32Little and kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst don't seem to be available anymore. Any idea what the new values could be?

Answer (score 5):

Convert above code to Swift 4

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class CameraViewController: UIViewController, AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var cameraImageView: UIImageView!

var device: AVCaptureDevice?
var captureSession: AVCaptureSession?
var previewLayer: AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer?
var cameraImage: UIImage?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    setupCamera()
    setupTimer()
}

func setupCamera() {
    let discoverySession = AVCaptureDevice.DiscoverySession(deviceTypes: [.builtInWideAngleCamera],
                                                            mediaType: AVMediaType.video,
                                                           position: .front)
    device = discoverySession.devices[0]

    let input: AVCaptureDeviceInput
    do {
        input = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: device!)
    } catch {
        return
    }

    let output = AVCaptureVideoDataOutput()
    output.alwaysDiscardsLateVideoFrames = true

    let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "cameraQueue")
    output.setSampleBufferDelegate(self, queue: queue)
    output.videoSettings = [kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey as AnyHashable as! String: kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA]

    captureSession = AVCaptureSession()
    captureSession?.addInput(input)
    captureSession?.addOutput(output)
    captureSession?.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSession.Preset.photo

    previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession!)
    previewLayer?.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.resizeAspectFill
    previewLayer?.frame = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: view.frame.width, height: view.frame.height)

    view.layer.insertSublayer(previewLayer!, at: 0)

        captureSession?.startRunning()
    }

    func captureOutput(_ output: AVCaptureOutput, didOutput sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer, from connection: AVCaptureConnection) {
        let imageBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer)
    CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(imageBuffer!, CVPixelBufferLockFlags(rawValue: 0))
        let baseAddress = UnsafeMutableRawPointer(CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(imageBuffer!))
        let bytesPerRow = CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRow(imageBuffer!)
        let width = CVPixelBufferGetWidth(imageBuffer!)
        let height = CVPixelBufferGetHeight(imageBuffer!)

        let colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()
        let newContext = CGContext(data: baseAddress, width: width, height: height, bitsPerComponent: 8, bytesPerRow: bytesPerRow, space: colorSpace, bitmapInfo:
        CGBitmapInfo.byteOrder32Little.rawValue | CGImageAlphaInfo.premultipliedFirst.rawValue)

        let newImage = newContext!.makeImage()
         cameraImage = UIImage(cgImage: newImage!)

        CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(imageBuffer!, CVPixelBufferLockFlags(rawValue: 0))
    }

    func setupTimer() {
        _ = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 2.0, target: self, selector: #selector(snapshot), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }

    @objc func snapshot() {
        print("SNAPSHOT")
        cameraImageView.image = cameraImage
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You probably need to use `AVFoundation` to capture the video stream/image without displaying it. Unlike `UIImagePickerController`, it doesn't work 'out-of-the-box'. Look at Apple's `AVCam` as an example to get you started.

Answer (score 3):

I converted the code above from Objc to Swift 3, if anyone still looks for a solution in 2017.

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class CameraViewController: UIViewController, AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var cameraImageView: UIImageView!

var device: AVCaptureDevice?
var captureSession: AVCaptureSession?
var previewLayer: AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer?
var cameraImage: UIImage?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    setupCamera()
    setupTimer()
}

func setupCamera() {
    let discoverySession = AVCaptureDeviceDiscoverySession(deviceTypes: [.builtInWideAngleCamera],
                                                           mediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo,
                                                           position: .front)
    device = discoverySession?.devices[0]

    let input: AVCaptureDeviceInput
    do {
        input = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: device)
    } catch {
        return
    }

    let output = AVCaptureVideoDataOutput()
    output.alwaysDiscardsLateVideoFrames = true

    let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "cameraQueue")
    output.setSampleBufferDelegate(self, queue: queue)
    output.videoSettings = [kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey as AnyHashable: kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA]

    captureSession = AVCaptureSession()
    captureSession?.addInput(input)
    captureSession?.addOutput(output)
    captureSession?.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto

    previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession)
    previewLayer?.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill

    previewLayer?.frame = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: view.frame.width, height: view.frame.height)

    view.layer.insertSublayer(previewLayer!, at: 0)

    captureSession?.startRunning()
}

func captureOutput(_ captureOutput: AVCaptureOutput!, didOutputSampleBuffer sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer!, from connection: AVCaptureConnection!) {
    let imageBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer)
    CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(imageBuffer!, CVPixelBufferLockFlags(rawValue: .allZeros))
    let baseAddress = UnsafeMutableRawPointer(CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(imageBuffer!))
    let bytesPerRow = CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRow(imageBuffer!)
    let width = CVPixelBufferGetWidth(imageBuffer!)
    let height = CVPixelBufferGetHeight(imageBuffer!)

    let colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()
    let newContext = CGContext(data: baseAddress, width: width, height: height, bitsPerComponent: 8, bytesPerRow: bytesPerRow, space: colorSpace, bitmapInfo:
        CGBitmapInfo.byteOrder32Little.rawValue | CGImageAlphaInfo.premultipliedFirst.rawValue)

    let newImage = newContext!.makeImage()
    cameraImage = UIImage(cgImage: newImage!)

    CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(imageBuffer!, CVPixelBufferLockFlags(rawValue: .allZeros))
}

func setupTimer() {
    _ = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 2.0, target: self, selector: #selector(snapshot), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}

func snapshot() {
    print("SNAPSHOT")
    cameraImageView.image = cameraImage
}
}
```

Also, I found a shorter solution for getting the image from the CMSampleBuffer:

```
func captureOutput(_ captureOutput: AVCaptureOutput!, didOutputSampleBuffer sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer!, from connection: AVCaptureConnection!) {
    let myPixelBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer)
    let myCIimage = CIImage(cvPixelBuffer: myPixelBuffer!)
    let videoImage = UIImage(ciImage: myCIimage)
    cameraImage = videoImage
}
```

Comment: No problem, I am glad it was useful, don't really know if it still works with Swift 4 without popping up warnings..

Comment: Not just warnings, some stuff needs to be altered, but the fix-its mostly handle it.

Answer (score 0):

There is a method called takePicture in the docs for UIImagePickerController class. It says:

Use this method in conjunction with a custom overlay view to initiate the programmatic capture of a still image. This supports taking more than one picture without leaving the interface, but requires that you hide the default image picker controls.