# iOS: Enable shutter sound while taking picture

Tags: ios, audio

I am using the following code: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14063081/1011125.

Now I need to enable the sound which is played if a picture is taken.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: want you play a sound when tap on button?

Comment: If you take a look at the code: the image is taken programmatically.. no button needs to be tapped :)

Comment: ok this is not a problem, want you play sound during the process right?

Comment: ok give me a minute ;)

Answer (score 1):

There's two ways to do that:

1) Using  `AVAudioPlayer`

In your `myPic.m` adding:

```
//at the top
#import <AudioToolbox/AudioToolbox.h>
#import <MediaPlayer/MediaPlayer.h>

@implementation myPic {

    AVAudioPlayer *mySound;

 }

//then use this function where ever you want to play sound

    NSString *soundFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource: @"mySound" ofType: @"mp3"]; //wav, aiff, ogg, ext
    NSURL *fileURL = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath: soundFilePath];
    loopUno = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL: fileURL error: nil];
    loopUno.numberOfLoops = 0; // here loop setup infinite is -1
    [mySound play];
```

2) i prefer, have no loop but is more stable is `SystemSoundID soundID`

```
    //at the top
    #import <AudioToolbox/AudioToolbox.h>
    #import <MediaPlayer/MediaPlayer.h>

    @implementation myPic {

         SystemSoundID soundID;

     }

//then use this function where ever you want to play sound
        AudioServicesDisposeSystemSoundID(soundID);
        CFBundleRef mainBundle = CFBundleGetMainBundle();
        CFURLRef soundFileURLRef;
        soundFileURLRef =  CFBundleCopyResourceURL(mainBundle, (CFStringRef) @"mySound" ,CFSTR ("mp3") , NULL); //wav, aiff, ogg, ext
        AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID(soundFileURLRef, &soundID);
        AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundID);
```

Override Speaker:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];

    AVAudioSession* session = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
    BOOL success;
    NSError* error;
    success = [session setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord error:&error];
    success = [session overrideOutputAudioPort:AVAudioSessionPortOverrideSpeaker error:&error];
    success = [session setActive:YES error:&error];
}
```

or if you use more audio in you app add the function inside you `AppDelegate.m` under `application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` and import your delegate where you need

Hope this help you ;)

Comment: Jhon, thank you very much for your answer. But Apple means that the sound in the code is disabled by default. So I need to enable it first.. and I don't know how.

Comment: post here the exact feedback you receive

Comment: try to use override speaker, I add for you on my answer

Comment: "Apps that enable recording a third party must provide reasonable means of indicating the recording activity. To address this issue, please ensure the shutter sound is not auto-disabled when a photo is taken."

Answer (score 0):

Place this code for shutter sound,

AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(1108);

**Note**: http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/AudioServices