# How to take picture of user's face anytime while using ARKit WorldTackingConfiguration

Tags: ios, swift, arkit, avcapturesession

I am using ARKit to place some 3D models and visualize it in real world. I want to take picture of User's face with click of a button programmatically while in AR View(Without showing the front camera screen to user). I followed this link [iOS: Capture image from front facing camera](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10199021/ios-capture-image-from-front-facing-camera) to capture the user's face.

But this works only till the AR session begins. As soon as the AR session begins, the below delegate method is not being called at all.

```
func captureOutput(_ output: AVCaptureOutput, didOutput sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer, from connection: AVCaptureConnection) {
}
```

If i call **setupCamera()** method (from the link) again, it interrupts the AR session.

Is there a way to take user's picture while they are looking at the AR view?

I tried combining **ARFaceTrackingConfiguration** and **ARWorldTrackingConfiguration** for tracking user's facial expressions but that also did not work. Looks like only one configuration can be active at a time.

Comment: AR uses the rear camera right? you cannot use the front and back cameras at the same time

Comment: @Scriptable So there is no way to achieve this? Can't we use both the cameras like in Video calls?

Comment: Apple can use both cameras... us developers cant