# take photo with both cameras like frontback

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, camera, photo

I am working on an app in which I am using camera. How can we take photo using both cameras like [Frontback](https://itunes.apple.com/be/app/frontback/id673566671?mt=8) and [DuoCam](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/duocam-take-two-sided-photos/id556850975?mt=8) at the same time on the same screen ?

Comment: See this link: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3919807/can-the-iphone4-record-from-both-front-and-rear-facing-camera-at-the-same-time

Comment: The Frontback app does not record video, it takes pictures. Also, it uses the two cameras one after the other (with the minimum possible delay) and not simultaneously

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called as RearCam & FrontCam

You can use it like

```
 if (_imagePicker.cameraDevice == UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceFront)
    _imagePicker.cameraDevice = UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceRear;
else
    _imagePicker.cameraDevice = UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceFront;
```

where _imagePicker -> an instance of the imagepickercontroller

Comment: hi why did you remove the accept from answer. Is this not true for you?

Comment: Well, your answer is correct but it will not fulfill my requirement. I want to record from both front facing camera and rear camera at the same time on the same screen using `AVSessionCapture`. Do you have any idea about this or any blog post regarding this ? Please see the Frontback app on the iTunes.