# Capturing from two cameras at the same time on Android 8.0

Tags: android, android-camera, android-8.0-oreo

Is it possible to simultaneously read from both the front and back cameras on Android 8.0? If so, how can one go about doing this?

Comment: check this out https://stackoverflow.com/q/17917182/2900127

Comment: There is nothing specific to Android 8. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/28811277/192373